# What will be the rewriterule to redirect when query is not a valid directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to write a rewriterule in .htaccess file to redirect all requests which does not specify a valid directory name.

for e.g. if i have 1 folder **test** and 1 file **index.php** in my website root directory. My requirement is that all requests which are requesting a page in **test** folder or subfolders will not be rewritten by the mod_rewrite and all other requests that doesnt start with test will be rewritten to **index.php**.

P.S. numbers of folders and their names are changed very often, that is why i was looking for a generic rewriterule which will check for valid directory names.

What will be rewriterule for above case?

Answer (score 0):

Do this in yout `.htaccess` of `DocumentRoot`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

Rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule  ^ index.php [L]
```

From [rewritecond <sup>apache docs</sup>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) :
`-f`, `-d` & `-l` are variants of CondPatterns. Instead of real regular expression strings.

> - '-d' (is directory)
>     Treats the TestString as a pathname and tests whether or not it exists, and is a directory.
> - '-f' (is regular file)
>     Treats the TestString as a pathname and tests whether or not it exists, and is a regular file.
> - '-l' (is symbolic link)
>     Treats the TestString as a pathname and tests whether or not it exists, and is a symbolic link.

if prefixed by an exclamation mark ('!') it leads to negate their meaning. i.e. `!-f` means is not a regular file.